# how to use gce loadbalancer for mysql loadbalancing

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I want to use google load balancer for mysql load balancing. First and foremost is the google documentation where they mentioned support for only few ports(line mentioned below). So should I assume that GCE load balancer can not be used ahead of mysql instances.

TCP proxy supports the following ports: 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995

Thanks,
Jag Nikam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information on the different GCE Load Balancers [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/) . Your SQL instances can be placed behind a [Regional Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/)

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine [TCP proxy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/tcp-proxy) works on a very basic level:

> With TCP proxying for your TCP traffic, you can terminate your
>   customers’ TCP sessions at the global load balancing layer, then
>   forward the traffic to your virtual machine instances using TCP or
>   SSL.

The port list is an indication that the GCE [TCP proxy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/tcp-proxy) is designed mainly for **email load balancing**:

- Email (SMTP `25`, submission `465` & `587`, POP3 `110` & `995`, IMAP `143` & `993`)
- WHOIS (`43`), EPP (`500`) and DNSIX ( `195`)
- HTTPS ( `443`, although [HTTP(S) load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) is recommended instead)

SQL load balancing is more complex. See [The Challenges of SQL Load Balancing](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/the-challenges-of-sql-load-balancing) by Lori MacVittie. The article mentions two points why GCE TCP load balancing may not support (/ work for) SQL:

> **If your application uses stored procedures, then this method will not
>   work for you.** It is important to note that many packaged enterprise
>   applications rely upon stored procedures, and are thus not able to
>   leverage load balancing as a scaling option. - -
>
> This also requires that the load balancing service parse MySQL or
>   T-SQL (the Microsoft Transact Structured Query Language). Databases,
>   of course, are designed to parse these string-based commands and are
>   optimized to do so. **Load balancing services are generally not designed
>   to parse these languages** and depending on the implementation of their
>   underlying parsing capabilities, may actually incur significant
>   performance penalties to do so.